# How to find pattern in javascript variable and return the founded element in array?

Tags: javascript

I will need your help to extract string pattern inside the JavaScript variable from the array.

For example, lets say:

- `var type = ["men","women","boys", "girls"]`
- `var product = "women shoes"`

I would like to write the function that search the variable **product** from my custom define variable **type**.

So the function can return the string "women".

Many thanks!!!

Allen

Comment: What did you try? Why didn't it work?

Comment: I am just a javascript beginner, however, I need to capture all useful variables for eCommerce site in the google tag manager.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd go with:

```
var type = ["men", "women", "boys", "girls"],
    product = "women shoes",
    result;

function filterData(item, index) {
   if (new RegExp( '\\b' + item + '\\b', 'i').test(product)) {
       return true;
   } 
   return false;
}

result = type.filter(filterData);
console.log(result);
```

Working example: https://jsfiddle.net/nc1qodk5/

Answer (score 0):

You should use `forEach` method.

First of all, you have to use `split` method in order to obtain an `array`. For instance, `var product="women shoes"` will be `var array=["women","shoes"]`.Then all you need is to seek every `elem` from `array` in your `type` array.

```js
var type = ["men","women","boys", "girls"]
var product = "women shoes";
product.split(' ').forEach(function(item){
    type.forEach(function(elem){
          if(elem==item){
            console.log(elem);
          }
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks Alex...your code works perfectly in GTM too!! Can't say enough thanks to you!!

Answer (score 0):

You can use a mix of `Array.prototype.filter()` and `indexOf()` after splitting the sentence

```js
var type = ["men","women","boys", "girls"]
var product = "women shoes";
var result = product.split(' ').filter(p => type.indexOf(p) !== -1);
console.log(result);
```

Comment: Thanks Weedoze for your help!!! Love how everyone do the same thing differently!! learnt a ton!

Answer (score 0):

```
function filterValue() {
    var temp="";
    for(var i=0;i<type.length;i++){
        if(product.indexOf(type[i])!==-1){
           temp=type[i];
           break;
        }
    }
    return temp;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Michael!!! indexOf(type[i])....never thought about that...love it!

Comment: Hello atsang01. Good to know you liked it.
Just wanted to say Michael edited it and I posted the answer.
Happy coding :)

Comment: Nitesh...my bad...Thanks to you too!!! still not very familiar with stackoverflow...but now i am loving it!! So powerful and love all the experts like u! :)